# Javascript: Image preview is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I will explain first the code

I have two views where I make a preview of a image (input file).

View where I have a form and I make a preview of the inputs file:

Create project view:

```
<table>
       <tr>
           <td>
               <img src="" id="img" class="img" style="width:100%;height:200px;background-color:#ccc;border:2px solid gray;" onerror="this.src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII='">
               <input type="file" name="pathheader" id="pathheader"  class="form-control-file" aria-describedby="fileHelp" style="display:none;">
           </td>
           <td>
               <img src="" id="img2" class="img2" style="width:100%;height:200px;background-color:#ccc;border:2px solid gray;" onerror="this.src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII='">
               <input type="file" name="pathhome" id="pathhome" class="form-control-file" aria-describedby="fileHelp" style="display:none;"><br>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>
               <input type="button" name="" value="Seleccionar header" id="browse_file" class="btn btn-danger form-control">
           </td>
           <td>
               <input type="button" name="" value="Seleccionar home" id="browse_file2" class="btn btn-danger form-control">
           </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Edit project view:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @if (Storage::disk('projects')->has($project->slug))
                   <img src="{{ asset('/storage/projects/'.$project->slug.'/header.jpg') }}" id="img" class="img" style="width:100%;height:200px;background-color:#ccc;border:2px solid gray;">
                @else
                   <img src="" id="img" class="img" style="width:100%;height:200px;background-color:#ccc;border:2px solid gray;">
                @endif
                   <input type="file" name="pathheader" id="pathheader" class="form-control-file" aria-describedby="fileHelp" style="display:none;">
            </td>
            <td>
                @if (Storage::disk('projects')->has($project->slug))
                   <img src="{{ asset('/storage/projects/'.$project->slug.'/home.jpg') }}" id="img" class="img" style="width:100%;height:200px;background-color:#ccc;border:2px solid gray;">
                @else
                   <img src="" id="img2" class="img2" style="width:100%;height:200px;background-color:#ccc;border:2px solid gray;">
                @endif
                   <input type="file" name="pathhome" id="pathhome" class="form-control-file" aria-describedby="fileHelp" style="display:none;"><br>
           </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <input type="button" name="" value="Seleccionar header" id="browse_file" class="btn btn-danger form-control">
          </td>
          <td>
              <input type="button" name="" value="Seleccionar home" id="browse_file2" class="btn btn-danger form-control">
          </td>
       </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript code:

```
$("#browse_file").on('click',function(e){
    $("#pathheader").click();
});
$("#browse_file2").on('click',function(e){
    $("#pathhome").click();
});

$("#pathheader").on('change',function(e){
    var fileInput=this;
    if (fileInput.files[0])
        {
            var reader=new FileReader();
            reader.onload=function(e)
            {
                $("#img").attr('src',e.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.files[0]);
        }
});

$("#pathhome").on('change',function(e){
    var fileInput=this;
    if (fileInput.files[0])
        {
            var reader=new FileReader();
            reader.onload=function(e)
            {
                $("#img2").attr('src',e.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.files[0]);
        }
});
```

When I select an image on create project view, code works, make a preview of the file.

**PROBLEM**

When I edit the project and I select two files I only see the preview of the new image in pathheader not in pathhome.

Why the preview of the new image on pathhome isn't working? I check errors and don't display any one.

Thanks a lot, and if need more information or just think isn't clear make me known it and I will try to explain it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an typo in your html code and maybe that's why the JavaScript isn't able to find the element

```
$("#img2").attr('src',e.target.result);
```

```
<td>
@if (Storage::disk('projects')->has($project->slug))
   <img src="{{ asset('/storage/projects/'.$project->slug.'/header.jpg') }}" id="img" class="img" style="width:100%;height:200px;background-color:#ccc;border:2px solid gray;">
@else
   <img src="" id="img" class="img" style="width:100%;height:200px;background-color:#ccc;border:2px solid gray;">
@endif
   

<td>
@if (Storage::disk('projects')->has($project->slug))
<img src="{{ asset('/storage/projects/'.$project->slug.'/home.jpg') }}" id="img" class="img" style="width:100%;height:200px;background-color:#ccc;border:2px solid gray;">
@else
<img src="" id="img2" class="img2" style="width:100%;height:200px;background-color:#ccc;border:2px solid gray;">
@endif
<input type="file" name="pathhome" id="pathhome" class="form-control-file" aria-describedby="fileHelp" style="display:none;">
```

Comment: Omg.. it's true. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your HTML TD with below one:

```
<tr>
    <!--FOR pathheader-->
    <td>
        @if (Storage::disk('projects')->has($project->slug))
            <img src="{{ asset('/storage/projects/'.$project->slug.'/header.jpg') }}" id="img" class="img" style="width:100%;height:200px;background-color:#ccc;border:2px solid gray;">
        @else
            <img src="" id="img" class="img" style="width:100%;height:200px;background-color:#ccc;border:2px solid gray;">
        @endif
        <input type="file" name="pathheader" id="pathheader" class="form-control-file" aria-describedby="fileHelp" style="display:none;">
    </td>
    <!--FOR pathhome-->
    <td>
        @if (Storage::disk('projects')->has($project->slug))
            <img src="{{ asset('/storage/projects/'.$project->slug.'/home.jpg') }}" id="img2" class="img2" style="width:100%;height:200px;background-color:#ccc;border:2px solid gray;">
        @else
            <img src="" id="img2" class="img2" style="width:100%;height:200px;background-color:#ccc;border:2px solid gray;">
        @endif
        <input type="file" name="pathhome" id="pathhome" class="form-control-file" aria-describedby="fileHelp" style="display:none;"><br>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Given wrong `id` and `class` value for `pathhome` > `@if`.